# How to make multi level treeview in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

I have the following code. This successfully creates a root view with a Model1 and a Model1. I am having trouble adding items to Model1 though. How can I do that?

```
@FXML
TreeView<String> locationTreeView;

public void loadTreeItems()
{


    ArrayList<String> rootItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    rootItems.add("Model1");
    rootItems.add("Model2");
    TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<String>("Root");

    root.setExpanded(true);
    for (String itemString : rootItems)
    {
        root.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String>(itemString));
    }

    locationTreeView.setRoot(root);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add them to the tree items you create, in the same way you added to the root item:

```
public void loadTreeItems()
{


    TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<String>("Root");

    root.setExpanded(true);

    TreeItem<String> model1 = new TreeItem<String>("Model1");
    TreeItem<String> model2 = new TreeItem<String>("Model2");

    TreeItem<String> model11 = new TreeItem<String>("Model1.1");
    TreeItem<String> model12 = new TreeItem<String>("Model1.2");

    root.getChildren().add(model1);
    root.getChildren().add(model2);

    model1.getChildren().add(model11);
    model1.getChildren().add(model12);

    locationTreeView.setRoot(root);
}
```

Obviously you can make loops to do this if you have some kind of repetitive structure.

Comment: Awesome. And do you happen to know how you would add an image right next to where you click it?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeItem.html#setGraphic-javafx.scene.Node-